# Patterns, PHP, ORM

Tags: php, design-patterns, orm

What are the best links for learning design patterns (orm too)?
I found this site, but you do not have standards orm (http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns)

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking this question regarding design patterns and OOP specifically for the PHP language can I recommend that you have a look at [PHP in Action](http://www.manning.com/reiersol/).  It's a great intro into OOP for PHP programmers; covers [SOLID design principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) and if I remember rightly it covers some of the most common patterns used in OO design.  I'm not sure if it goes over ORM frameworks (or patterns) but if you want more information on that then do a quick google search for the [repository pattern](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=repository%20pattern&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-GB%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&safe=active).

Answer (score 0):

Check: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-designptrns/

Answer (score 0):

There is a single file php orm called db.php and it has very cute code after reading this:

http://dbphp.net/basic-architecture/

I than looked in db.php code at https://github.com/hazardland/db.php/blob/master/db.php and I suddenly become well educated about orm basic architecture.